# Error 1452 MySQL Load Infile (but correct data)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1452

I'm trying to load data from a .txt using LOAD DATA INFILE, the problem is that i get error 1452, but the foreign keys referred are present in my DB. Also other LOAD DATA are working, just can't solve this and 1 other load.

I've checked the referred data, and are present in DB before i load. Also the columns are of the same type. I tried reinstalling MySQL still not working (but a friend of mine using the same code/.txt can load the data). I can load the .txt if it consists of a single line, but when adding a second one i got the error.

```
-- The table referred:
CREATE TABLE Categoria (
Nome    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
Immagine    MEDIUMBLOB,
PRIMARY KEY (Nome));

-- The table with FK:
CREATE TABLE Sottocategoria_Di (
Categoria1  VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
Categoria2  VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Categoria1, Categoria2),
FOREIGN KEY (Categoria1) REFERENCES Categoria(Nome) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY (Categoria2) REFERENCES Categoria(Nome) ON DELETE CASCADE);

INSERT INTO Categoria VALUES ('Chitarra', NULL);
INSERT INTO Categoria VALUES ('Chitarra Acustica', NULL);
INSERT INTO Categoria VALUES ('Chitarra Classica', NULL);

LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 
8.0/Uploads/MusicShop/Sottocategoria.txt" INTO TABLE 
Music.Sottocategoria_Di
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Categoria1,Categoria2);

-- Sottocategoria.txt
Categoria1,Categoria2
Chitarra Classica|Chitarra
Chitarra Acustica|Chitarra
```

A friend of mine reinstalled MySQL and using the same exact script/.txt can load the file but i still can't.

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`music`.`sottocategoria_di`, CONSTRAINT `sottocategoria_di_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Categoria2`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`Nome`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: Is that a backtick at the end of the second row?

Comment: Yes, missclicked copying it, but in my .txt is not present.

Comment: 2 things to check 1) you are supplying categoria2 in the data but they are set to null in categoria 2) you may need to amend lines terminated by to LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Comment: Thanks for help! That worked! The problem was using '\n', switched to '\r\n' and it worked! Still don't know why it works for other files .txt i'm using (still on Windows)

Comment: Please don't edit SOLVED into titles or solutions into questions. Post your answer as an answer. After a minimum time you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using lines terminated by '\n', switched to '\r\n' and it worked! Still don't know why it works for other files .txt i'm using (same OS Windows)